# Is it possible to configure token separator characters with AWS Cloudsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

My Cloudsearch index currently returns no results for `one-two three` but it does return one result (correctly) for `one two three` (and will also be included, correctly, in the results when searching for `two three` etc.)

My understanding is that this is because searchable phrases are broken down into their tokens (words) with whitespace **and punctuation** acting as delimiters. So, `one` and `two` become separate tokens, but `one-two` is not a valid token, so no results are found. From the [Cloudsearch docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/text-processing.html):

> During tokenization, the stream of text in a field is split into separate tokens on detectable boundaries using the word break rules defined in the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm.

That Unicode document [is here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/).

I would like to be able to search for `one-two three` and find the relevant result, as well as a few other punctuation characters, like `/`. Is it possible to configure this with Cloudsearch?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized a simple solution to this that works fine, although it technically does not answer my question. I simply needed to pre-process my query strings before sending them to cloud search by replacing `-` or `/` or whatever char I want with a single space.

That way, `one-two three` actually performs a search for `one two three`, returning the correct result.

Comment: That's lame, you shouldn't have to change your corpus to meet AWS restriction. Doesn't it support WordDelimiterFilterFactory?